# How to send test results to another place on elixir

Tags: elixir, ex-unit

When I run mix test I get all the results back in the shell.
How can I get the results to more places like slack, files etc..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer for my question in https://stackoverflow.com/a/41350442/11678286.
To config your own configuration for ExUnit results I need to implement my own formatter (see https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/ex_unit/lib/ex_unit/cli_formatter.ex for an example; that's the default formatter) and configure ExUnit to use it:

`ExUnit.start(formatters: [YourFormatterModule])`

For send the result to other places (like slack) I just need to copy the default formatter and add function there that send it to salck too.

Answer (score 1):

To write the results of `mix test` to a file you can do:

```
mix test > results.txt
```

To post them on Slack you can use their web API, which you can find here: https://api.slack.com/web

Comment: Your suggestion is local solution, I want some thing that can automatically do it and give me control on the massage. I have in my code connection to slack API but I don't know how can I get the logs so I can send there.

Comment: You could read the file and send the content using curl.
`results=cat results.txt`
`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/plain" --data $results  http://api.slack.com`

Comment: There is no way to configure in the app some how?